# How can i use ternary operator to display different elements in different positon Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've the following setup.
I've a config file where I define  `postsPerPage: 2`

On my main page, I display posts regarding the posts per Page value. I need to display the posts in the following manner.

```
https://prnt.sc/qbrtka
https://prnt.sc/qbru7k
```

So what I need to achieve is that if there is one post already displayed, use template 2, else use template 1. 
(the first post has the image on the left side and text on right)
(the 2nd post has the image on right side and the text on left)
I do  have the templates working, i need the logic

I have the following vars to work with

```
const rowsPerPage = postsPerPage;
const totalResult = blogposts.length;
```

I tried to make a new var like

```
const active = rowsPerPage - 1;
```

and use active as ternary element

```
 {active > 1 ? (
```

but sadly i cant get the logic.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're looping through a list of posts and rendering them. You could do something like this in order to use different templates based on the position in the list:

```
{this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
    const isEven = index % 2 === 0
    return isEven
      ? <Template1 key={index} post={post} />
      : <Template2 key={index} post={post} />
}}
```

This example renders `Template1` for even and `Template2` for odd posts.

Or, to just have the first one different:

```
{this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
    return index === 0
      ? <Template1 key={index} post={post} />
      : <Template2 key={index} post={post} />
}}
```